# How can I change this PhantomJS script to NodeJS for web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

This is PhantomJS script that I use for scraping HTML DOM in web page. That use for waiting all DOM ready

```
//scrap_phantom.js
var server = require("webserver").create();
var page = require("webpage").create();
var port = require('system').env.PORT || 3000;
var url = "http://www.example.com";

server.listen(port, function (request, response) {
    function onPageReady() {
        var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function () {  
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        });
        response.write(htmlContent);
        response.close();
        phantom.exit();
    }
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        function checkReadyState() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var readyState = page.evaluate(function () {
                    return document.readyState;
                });
                if ("complete" === readyState) {
                    onPageReady();
                } else {
                    checkReadyState();
                }
            });
        }
        checkReadyState();
    });
});
```

I'm testing it in cmd with "phantomjs scrap_phantom.js". The above code will work. Now, I change this code to NodeJS script like this:

```
//scrap_node.js
var http = require("http");
var phantom = require('phantom');
var url = "http://www.example.com";

http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
    function onPageReady() {
        var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function () {  
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        });
        response.write(htmlContent);
        response.close();
        phantom.exit();
    }

phantom.create(function (ph) {
    return ph.createPage(function (page) {
        page.open(url, function (status) {
            function checkReadyState() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var readyState = page.evaluate(function () {
                        return document.readyState;
                    });
                    if ("complete" === readyState) {
                        onPageReady();
                    } else {
                        checkReadyState();
                    }
                });
            }
            checkReadyState();
        });
    });
    }, {
        dnodeOpts: {weak: false}
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

I'm testing it in cmd with "node scrap_node.js". This code will not work for me. It's loading for a long time and it doesn't return any errors. Why is it not working for me?

Comment: "This code will not work for me" is not an appropriate description of what is going on. Do you see errors? What is the output and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: "http://www.example.com" that is "http://pantip.com/topic/31403893" @ArtjomB. It 's load for long time ... don't have any error return. I don't see it. Browser on localhost:3000 show >>> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. <<<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

phantomjs-node is a bridge between node.js and PhantomJS. It uses a slightly different syntax and none of its functions is synchronous. This means that if you write this in PhantomJS:

```
var result = page.evaluate(function(arg1, arg2){
    //...1
    return stuff;
}, "arg1", "arg2");
//...2
```

Then the equivalent in phantomjs-node (see [Functionality Details](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details)) is this:

```
page.evaluate(function(arg1, arg2){
    //...1
    return stuff;
}, function(result){
    //...2
}, "arg1", "arg2");
```

It is inherently asynchronous.

The other thing is that `phantom` doesn't have an `exit` function, but `ph` does.

Furthermore, `setTimeout(function(){...})` isn't doing anything useful. You need to pass some timeout value for it to be useful.